# Need to display monthly data excluding 2 months of data

Tags: tableau-api

Im trying to design a dashboard wherein I need a parameter to control 2 things.
If I select "Rolling 12",  I should be able to see the last 12 months of my data with respect to current month. When I select "Rolling 12-2", I should be able to see

last 12 months of my data but excluding the latest 2 months. E.g If I'm in January 2018 then I should be able to see data excluding Jan 18 and Dec 17 (from Jan 17 to Nov 17). I have tried some techniques but without success. Can anyone help. Thanks.

Reference Tableau Workbook attached at [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aOzVY2gYvh7H1TOG3xV1Y5yVh3ingoxv) :

Answer (score 1):

Using the Superstore sample data (I don't have 10.5 installed), I created the following boolean expression which you'd put in the filter shelf for True.

Give a parameter called `rolling`, create calc field as follows:

```
if [rolling] = 'Rolling 12' 
then DATEDIFF('month',[Order Date],{max([Order Date])}) < 12
ELSEIF [rolling] = 'Rolling 12-2' 
then DATEDIFF('month',[Order Date],{max([Order Date])}) < 12
and DATEDIFF('month',[Order Date],{max([Order Date])}) >= 2
end
```

Adjust the date name for your date field.

Comment: can we do this by table calculations by any chance ?

Comment: Can you explain more? You can make a table view with columns as months and it just displays based on the parameter selection.

Comment: Hi Bernado, I resolved this by taking a window avg of the last 12 months. I have another question on this which i have posted seperately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746209/need-to-take-window-average-of-last-3-months-for-my-sales

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help